# Sql Azure Export to CSV

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloud, azure-sql-database

I am trying to export Sql Azure table to CSV. When I right click on Database I see Tasks / Export Datatier application. Where Can I see the option to export data to csv from Sql Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows 10 and have SSMS and the Client tools, you should be able to just go to the search window and type 'Import and Export Data' to find the Import and Export Data program (which is basically the SQL Server Export Wizard).

For some reason the choice doesn't show up in SSMS for Azure databases - but you can run the wizard as the stand alone app - and it works fine with Azure databases.  More detail at: http://bpmdeveloper.com/sql-server-export-wizard-csv/

Comment: Note to all who are browsing this thread - this solution will not work if you have to authenticate with Azure AAD.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two straight forward solutions if you are okay with pulling the csv to your working environment:

Use SSMS to query your data with quoted column names, then right click in the results window, and click 'save results as'.

The same process can be followed with Azure Data Studio, but instead of right clicking, you can click the 'save as csv' button to the right of the query results.